# Port already in use in docker and springboot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

I am running springboottest and inside that running docker test containers. 8080 is used by wslrelay.exe. And when springboot tries to start server, address already in use exception is coming. I am using random port only in test, but everytime it is taking 8080. How to pass defined port to maven command line argument for the command mvn clean install? Why docker wslrelay.exe is always taking hold of port 8080?It is working till yesterday facing this issue from today only.

While running the individual test i passed the port other than 8080 and it is working.
But while running mvn clean install unable to pass the port for the test.Could you please tell the command to pass the port to mvn clean install?

Comment: It will be of great help if you tell us how your container is running ( docker run command ), your environment (windows, linux), if you are trying to run everything on the same machine and what kind of service is running inside the container. Show us some of your architecture.

Comment: From what little I could understand, you are on a windows host and run "wslrelay.exe", which occupies port 8080. Then you run a container with a service that also occupies port 8080. If that is the case, use Docker port redirection option  ( ```-p EXT_PORT:INT_PORT```).

Comment: I am using docker desktop for windows. I am running the test container like postgree in my springboot test. Before the start of embedded server the while testcontainer is running wslrelay.exe is occupying 8080, my jetty server is also trying to start on 8080. Why wslrelay.exe is running on 8080 when a testcontainer is running in docker.

Comment: Can you share the commands you are using to start your container? What do you mean "postgree in my springboot test" ? You can have only one service per container. You cannot start a Java Spring Boot together a postgreSQL. 
I'll ask you again to share details of your infrastructure.

Comment: In my local machine, I am running docker desktop and just using the testcontainers for my integration tests in springboot application.

Comment: Can you share the commands you are using to start your container?

Comment: https://1kevinson.com/integration-testing-with-springboot-docker-and-tests-containers/amp/.   This is the sample of how I am running docker test containers

Comment: I'll not read tutorials just to know what you're doing bro. I've made direct questions to you to try to help, but seems you really don't know what you're doing. Edit your question and put there what I asked you. I'll stop here until you clarify your problem.

Comment: I can see you're new here. So it would be nice if you read some S.O. directives about how to post questions.